# New vector position

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d

How can I calculate the new position of a 'point', with just a distance value coming from the center of the selection.

Example: I have 8 vertices selected, I have a little script in Maya that will iterate through each point, find the distance from the center of the selection to the current point in the loop. It saves these values and creates an "average distance from the center" value.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math
sel = cmds.ls(sl=1, fl=1)
averageDistance = 0
cmds.setToolTo('Move')
oldCoordArray = []
cs = cmds.manipMoveContext("Move", q=1, p=1)
for i in range(0, len(sel), 1):
    vts = cmds.pointPosition(sel[i])
    x = round(float(cs[0]),4) - round(float(vts[0]),4)
    y = round(float(cs[1]),4) - round(float(vts[1]),4)
    z = round(float(cs[2]),4) - round(float(vts[2]),4)
    distanceFromCenter = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z))
    print "Start Point: X: %s Y: %s Z: %s" %(round(float(cs[0]),4),round(float(cs[1]),4),round(float(cs[2]),4))
    print "End Point: X: %s Y: %s Z: %s" %(round(float(vts[0]),4),round(float(vts[1]),4),round(float(vts[2]),4))
    print "Distance: %s" %distanceFromCenter
    oldCoordArray += [(round(float(vts[0]),4),round(float(vts[1]),4),round(float(vts[2]),4))]
    averageDistance += distanceFromCenter
    if (i == len(sel) -1):
        averageDistance / len(sel)
        for i in range(0, len(sel), 1):
            #New position = oldCoordArray[i] - newCoordArray[i]
            print oldCoordArray[i]
```

Once this script has processed, I have these variables:

1. It's Old position in (X,Y,Z)
2. A new average distance from the center point.
3. I also have available the old distance from the centerpoint.

I'm assuming to calculate the new position, I'd have to find the new (X,Y,Z) values using the average distance that I've calculated, but I don't know how unfortunately.

**EDIT**

[Link To Image](http://www.shannonhochkins.com/_images/51356069965f59b00b00011f)

- Black = Each vertex position (X,Y,Z)
- Red = Distance between center and vertex
- Blue = Average of ALL verts from the Centerpoint (X,Y,Z) & Vertex (X,Y,Z) = integerXYZ (blue is the same distance)
- Green is the position I'm trying to find in (XYZ)

Am I doing this wrong, for blue, should I be averaging each single axis? example:

- BlueX= Average of CenterpointX & vertexX
- BlueY= Average of CenterpointY & vertexY
- BlueZ= Average of CenterpointZ & vertexZ
- GreenX, GreenY, GreenZ = BlueX, BlueY, BlueZ

Is that correct?

Comment: Seeing as I have the old distance and the new average distance, could I calculate what distance the average distance is of the old distance. `(10 * 50 / 100)`, and use that percentage to either to calculate the difference from the percentage?

`oldX += percentageDifference * oldX / 100`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you want to compute the new center so that it has a minimum average distance to each point?  If so, compute average distances in each of the coordinates separately.  These three average coordinates will give you the new center point.

Comment: When you say 'compute', that doesn't really answer it for me... what do I have to calculate?

Comment: I guess I meant, compute the average coordinate in each axis separately (i.e. x, y, z).

Comment: That wouldn't work, that would give me one co-ordinate, I need a different one per iteration? Or do you mean average it each time?

Comment: But still, the average distanceX and the originaldistanceX averaged, would be am average of an average...

Comment: observing your code, it appears that you are summing the coordinates in oldCoordArray.  If you divide by the number of points, you should have the center of the points.

Comment: no, The oldCoordArray is building an array of coordinates, oldCoord Array would look something like this if printed. `[(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]`

Comment: So you have 8 points (for example) and a center point.  You want to update the 8 points based on their distance to the center point.  It is not clear what you want the new points to be based on their distance to the center point.  Please clarify

Comment: I have just updated my question, does that help a bit? @Tpofofn

Answer (score 1):

So you want to compute new points that are each respectively on the line connecting the center and the old point.  Each of these new points is a distance of "averageDistance" from the center point.

Call the center point $c$ (cs above) and the points $v_i$ (vts above).  Let the new point be $n_i$.  Then you can compute the new point as follows:

$$ n_i = \frac{(v_i - c)}{\|v_i - c\|}*averageDistance + c$$

Comment: Thankyou Typofofn, So what are the '∥' symbolizing? other than that I understand the rest of it

Comment: Just the magnitude of the vector.  I believe that you compute it in your first loop and call it distanceFromCenter.

Comment: so the the expression would be `npX = (vts[0] - cs[0]) / (distanceFromCenter - cs[0]) * averageDistance + cs[0]`

Is that correct? obviously this would just calculate the new X value, and I'd have to repeat this 2 more times, but is that correct?

Comment: Almost.  You should use: npX = (vts[0] - cs[0]) / (distanceFromCenter[for this point]) * averageDistance + cs[0]

Comment: I'll have to try this out tonight, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321384/calculating-new-vector-positions, It's a similar end result, but this equasion is a little different to yours, here's hoping that your order is correct! You wouldn't mind reading of the post in the link I have added to this would you? I still have a few other problems to address :(

Comment: It is essentially the same equation just written a different way.  The steps you need to go through are as follows: (1) compute the average distance, (2) compute the relative vector to the center $v_i - c$, (3) normalize it to unit length by dividing it by its own length, (4) scaling it to the average length and then finally (5) adding the center back onto the result.  The referenced post does essentially the same thing, except that it distributes the scaling to each component.

Comment: I don't understand why/how to get it to 'average' it's new position. so that on all axis, it's a 'flat' circle, do I have to do something else to get it to evaluate this way?

Comment: Is the axis aligned with one of your coordinate axes.  If so, then you can omit that axis in your calculations.  Don't include it in your distance calculations and don't include it in your scaling calculations.  If it is not aligned with a coordinate axis, then you need something more sophisticated.